# Get text cursor across any application on Linux/Windows/Mac in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Question: I am trying to get the current text cursor position across any app using python 3. For example, in windows when hitting win + . an emoji input opens up right next to the currently used text input.

Similar to this, I want to get the text cursor position at any moment for any application.

What I tried: I tried using different libraries like pyautogui but I couldn't find any solution. Other stackoverflow questions lead me to believe that this can only be done with some native modules? Then my next questions would be what I need to google to find these OS specific functionalities?

Thanks in advance